# Want to populate listbox value when page loads without using any database in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to write a code where I can populate number from 1 to 20 in listbox when page loads.I have found many tutorials where they all have used database.

i am getting following error

> > System.NullReferenceException
> >     Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Class:

```
public class NumberClass
{
      public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> numbers { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<int> Selectednumbers { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Selectednumbers, Model.numbers)    
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
      List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
      NumberClass num = new NumberClass();
      for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
      {
          SelectListItem selectList = new SelectListItem()
          {
              Text = i.ToString(),
              Value = i.ToString()                 
          };

          items.Add(selectList);
      }
      return View();
}
```

Comment: Maybe this link will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000437/asp-net-mvc-populate-bind-data-in-listbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the list in view, then only you can get the list which you wants to populate.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
      List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
      NumberClass num = new NumberClass();
      for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
      {
          SelectListItem selectList = new SelectListItem()
          {
              Text = i.ToString(),
              Value = i.ToString()                 
          };

          items.Add(selectList);
      }
      return View(items);
}
```